# JavaFX - How to limit input method in PasswordField

Tags: javafx, input, methods, passwords

Like the title, when user input the password, I want to change the input method to English status automatically.

There is a bug in the picture, when user input the password, and the input method is not English status, it may expose user password.

[image]

Comment: Regarding the password exposure problem, why don't you use a [PasswordField](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/PasswordField.html)? It doesn't expose password based on language

Comment: This is a problem with the IME and has nothing to do with the control.

Comment: This probably isn't possible in JavaFX - see [this feature request](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8091266).

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work.